# Android: Align items and title/prompt in "Dialog" mode Spinner

Tags: android, android-layout, spinner

I have a spinner that's populated like this:

```
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.m_spinner);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerValuesList);
 spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
    spinner.setPrompt("CPU Frequency Governor");
```

It's created like this:

```
 <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog"
        android:id="@+id/my_spinner"/>
```

Everything works fine, but I'd like to align the text of the dialog title and the spinner items. I attached a picture to show what it currently looks like and what I'm looking to achieve.

[image: Spinner/Prompt alignment]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerValuesList);
```

Try this:

```
 final ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
, spinnerValuesList);
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work, results in nearly the exact same thing.

Comment: why dont you try passing your own textview in this... in that you can give padding margins colors as you need them